# Mongo aggregates: sum the number of bytes of BinData field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which contains a BinData. Here is an example doc :

- _id: int
- origLength: int (uncompressed size)
- uploadDate: ISODate
- data: (compressed data at application level)

I want to perform some size check.

I'm able to sum the uncompressed size, I can see the mongo db size. But I have no obvious way to count the total size of the data field. I can't find any aggregate function that return the BinData size.

```
db.passage.aggregate([{
  $group: {
      _id: 1, 
      count:{$sum : 1}, 
      totalBytes : {$sum : "$origLength"}, 
      compressedSize: {$sum : $XXX("$data")}}
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**aggregate** hasn't the operator to do this currently.
It's an option to use server-side js code.

```
db.eval(function() {
    var len = 0;
    db.passage.find({},{_id: 0, data: 1}).forEach(function(doc) {
        var b = doc.data;
        if (b instanceof BinData) {
            len += b.length();
        }
    });
    return len;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update MongoDB 4.4 introduces the $binarySize() into the aggregation framework